# Question on gcc of local array variable and inline functions when linking with own .ids files

Tags: c, gcc, inline, ld

I'm using gcc to compile a printing function. But met the following 2 problems:

1. Whenever I apply a local array type variable, the linker would report and error of "**undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'**"
2. When I'm using "inline" to define a function, it report an error of "**undefined reference to `strlen'**"

My platform is Ubuntu 18.04, and gcc version is 7.3.0.

I present some of the problem codes:

In function "number()" I applied an "char" type array variable, which actually cause the 1st error:

```
char* number(char *str, long num, int base, int field_width, int precision, int type)
{
    char *TempDgt = DigitsCptl, c, sign;
    int i;
    char TempStr[50];
    ....
    return str;
}
```

The problem lies on "char TempStr[50];" and with the removal of it, the link succeed. Similar problem appears on "va_list args;" of the following code:

```
int color_printk(unsigned int FRcolor, unsigned int BKcolor, char * fmt, ...)
{
    int count, i, line;
    va_list args;
    ...
    return i;
}
```

Second problem lies on function "strlen" as follow:

```
inline int strlen(char * String)
{
    ...
    return __res;
}
```

This time the "inline" descriptor caused the problem.

Both of the problems occur at "ld" instruction, the following is my makefile:

```
Kernel:

# Clear previous files

    - rm head.s head.o main.o system kernel.bin printk.o

# Compile head.S

    gcc -E  ./OSFiles/Codes/head.S > head.s

    as --64 -o head.o head.s

# Compile main function

    gcc  -mcmodel=large -fno-builtin -m64 -c ./OSFiles/Codes/main.c

    gcc  -mcmodel=large -fno-builtin -m64 -c ./OSFiles/Codes/printk.c

# Link compiled files

    ld -b elf64-x86-64 -z muldefs -o system head.o main.o printk.o -T ./OSFiles/Codes/Kernel.lds

# Dump out Kernel.bin

    objcopy -I elf64-x86-64 -S -R ".eh_frame" -R ".comment" -O binary system Kernel.bin
```

And the .ids file:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64","elf64-x86-64","elf64-x86-64")

OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)

ENTRY(_start)



SECTIONS

{

    . = 0xffff800000000000 + 0x100000;

    .text :

    {

        _text = .;

        *(.text)



        _etext = .;

    }

    .data :

    {

        _data = .;

        *(.data)

        _edata = .;

    }

    .bss :

    {

        _bss = .;

        *(.bss)

        _ebss = .;

    }

    _end = .;

}
```

Comment: In "compile head.S", why are you passing "-E" option? This is used to emit the preprocessor output. The reason for `undefined reference to __stack_chk_fail` is either that you are missing some library or this symbol might be defined somewhere n the linker script.

Comment: @consistentprogrammer It is from the book, it use gcc to output some pre-complie files first. However, the output is same as the original file. So I may be "as" it straight way. The "undefined reference to __stack_chk_fail" actually disappear after I move the application of array variable outside of the function....... which means that I may not be able to apply local array variable......